# Bounded minimum value problem (from an exam today in Australia).

Tags: limits, functions, upper-lower-bounds

A question appeared in today's exam in Victoria (Australia), in which a graphical calculator was also allowed to be used (just for context).
This question is causing some 'controversy', both in the interpretation of the wording, as well as the actual answer.

> Consider the function $g_a(x)=\sin(\frac{x}{a})+\cos(ax), a\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}. \text{ and } x\in \mathbb{R}$. State the greatest possible minimum value of $g_a$ (1 mark).

(This is not necessarily word for word (except for the last sentence), but this was indeed the premise of the question)

For this, I stated that this value is $-\sqrt2$, occurring for $a=1$. Upon graphing, if we call the minimum value $m$, it becomes clear that $-2<m\leq-\sqrt{2}$. (The $-2$ can be seen as this only occurs upon the superposition of minima, which never occurs but does get *approached*).

Now, a solution posted online is that:

$$\lim_{a\to \infty}g_a(x)=\cos(ax) \\ \therefore \min(g_a)=-1$$

However, to me this limit is nonsensical as the value of $x$ for which the minimum occurs increases as $a\to \infty$ sufficiently so as for there to always exist a value of $x$ such that $-2<g_a(x)\leq-\sqrt{2}$, even if this occurs for very large (negative or positive) values of $x$. This can be seen just by graphing on something like Desmos, where if zoomed out, you will see the value go below $-1$.

What is a *mathematically rigorous* way of showing this, seeing as this was given to Year 12s?

Comment: In addition to your point, it is not even true that $\lim_{a \to \infty}g_a(x) = \cos ax$, as should be obvious because $a \to \infty$, and thus is not available to be used on the right hand side. It is true that $\sin \frac xa \to 0$, but $\cos ax$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ as $a$ increases, so the limit does not converge.

Comment: Here's a sketch of a rigorous argument. Let $a$ be large. Note that if $x_0=3\pi a/2$ then $\sin(x_0/a)=-1$. Show that if $x_0-1<x<x_0+1$ then $\sin(x/a)$ is close to $-1$. Show that $\cos(ax)$ goes through a full period for $x_0-1<x<x_0+1$, in particular, takes on the value $-1$ for some $x=x^*$ in that interval. Then $g_a(x^*)$ is close to $-2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like attacking this with the "standard tools" (derivatives to find extreme points) will not work for general $a$. For $a=1$ it boils down to solving

$$g'_1(x) =\cos(x) - \sin(x)=0,$$

which should be doable for a students, yielding the minimum of $-\sqrt{2}$ that you also found. But for $a=2$ it already becomes

$$g'_2(x) =\frac12\cos\left(\frac{x}2\right) - 2\sin(2x)=0,$$

which I wouldn't know how to attack except with expanding everything in terms of $\tan\left(\frac{x}4\right)$, yielding to (it looks like) a polynomial equation of degree $8$. This seems certainly well out what to expect from year $12$ students. And of course higher $a$ make this even more complicated.

If anyone has a good method to solve that, I'd be interested!

A nice method to "solve" the $a=1$ case without looking at derivatives is to consider that

$$g_1(x)^2=(\sin(x) + \cos(x))^2 = \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) + 2 \sin(x)\cos(x) = 1 + \sin(2x) \le 2\; \forall x \in \mathbb R,$$

implying $|g_1(x)| \le \sqrt{2}$ and finally $g_1(x) \ge -\sqrt{2}$. Together with $g_1(\frac{5\pi}4)=-\frac12\sqrt{2} - \frac12\sqrt{2}= - \sqrt{2}$ this proves that the minimum of $g_1(x)$ over the reals is really $-\sqrt{2}$.

To show that $-\sqrt{2}$ is indeed the greatest possible minimum, I'd like to re-frame the question a bit.

Consider

$$f_a(x):=g_a(ax) = \sin(x) + \cos(a^2x).$$

The map $x \to ax$ is a bijection from $\mathbb R$ onto itself. So the minimum value of $g_a(x)$ is also the minimum value of $f_a(x)$, it's just taken at a different argument (which we don't care about).

$f_a(x)$ has some advantages over $g_a(x)$ for understanding it (at least for me):

1. it is the sum of 2 parts, one of which is no longer dependent on $a$, and
2. it is periodic with a period not depending on $a$, namely $2\pi$.

This gives us a shot to prove that for $a \ge 2$, the minimum of $f_a(x)$ is at most $-\frac12\sqrt{2} - 1 < -\sqrt{2}.$

To do that, first fix $a \ge 2$ and consider the interval $I=[\frac{5\pi}4, \frac{7\pi}4]$. On that interval, $\sin(x)$ is always at or below $-\frac12\sqrt{2}$, at the endpoints of $I$ the sine function takes this value. That interval has length $\frac\pi 2$.

Also note that $\cos(a^2x)$ has a period $p_a=\frac{2\pi}{a^2}$. For $a \ge 2$, that means $p_a \le \frac{2\pi}{2^2}=\frac\pi 2$.

So $\cos(a^2x)$ goes over the full wave it represents in any interval of length $\frac\pi 2$, which is also the length of the Interval $I$ defined above. That means there is some point $x_0 \in I$ with $\cos(a^2x_0)=-1$.

That means, taken together with the property of $I$ regarding the sine function, that

$$f_a(x_0)=\sin(x_0) + \cos(a^2x_0) = \sin(x_0) - 1 \le -\frac12\sqrt{2} - 1 < -\sqrt{2}.$$

Since there is an argument to $f_a$ that produces a value less than $-\sqrt{2}$ (for $a \ge 2$), the minimum of $f_a$ must obviously also be less than $-\sqrt{2}$,
finally proving that $-\sqrt{2}$, is actually the greatest minimum, take when $a=1$.

Comment: Amazing, I was trying to go on a similar train of thought which was fruitless if working with $g_a$. Thank you very much!